# Endpoint with the same key was already added when multiple consumers with InMemoryTestHarness

Tags: c#, masstransit

In one of my service tests, I use a InMemoryTestHarness with two consumers and a saga state machine instance:

```
harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();

harness.Consumer(() => new PrepareQueryFileConsumer(
loggerFactoryMock.Object,
tdMatchingRepositoryMock.Object,
sendEndpointProviderMock.Object), TDMatchingConfiguration.QueueName);

harness.Consumer(() => new RequestQueryFileConversionConsumer(
loggerFactoryMock.Object,
tdMatchingRepositoryMock.Object,
tdMatchingQueryFileRepositoryMock.Object,
fileConversionServiceMock.Object), TDMatchingConfiguration.QueueName);

var machine = new TDMatchingStateMachine();
var repository = new InMemorySagaRepository<TDMatchingState>();
harness.StateMachineSaga(machine, repository, TDMatchingConfiguration.QueueName);

await harness.Start();
```

This configuration results to the following error when "harness.Start();" is called:

> MassTransit.ConfigurationException: 'An exception occurred during bus creation'
> A receive endpoint with the same key was already added: td-matching

Everything works fine if I only have one consumer/state machine. So I understand that the endpoint is recreated on every addition, but how can I avoid this?

Comment: You might try using different queue names for each item, or leave the queue name off so that it uses the default unit test queue.

Comment: Um, maybe there's something I didn't understand in the concept. I use a single queue to make sure that all components can communicate with each other. And the default queue name cannot be used because in the internal activities of my state machine the name of the queue is hardcoded via the constant TDMatchingConfiguration.QueueName. Isn't this a good practice?

Comment: And to be sure, because this code works on a real bus, what you suggest is a workaround and there is a bug or a missing feature with the InMemoryTestHarness ?

Comment: Seems like a limitation of the in-memory test harness setup.